# Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given. Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new in php and having problem with a piece of my code if the key given exist. The code of error are below and i don't have a idea what is causing it. Please help.

"Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in"

The line

```
if ( is_array(array_key_exists('sizes',wp_get_attachment_metadata($attach_id)) == false ){}
```

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_metadata($attach_id)` is returning a `boolean` instead of an array. Usually meaning the metadata for those attachments weren't found.

Comment: Not answering your question but: `is_array(array_key_exists(...` does not make much sense. array_key_exists returns an bool, and is_array expects an array ...

Answer (score 1):

As ArSeN already pointed out, `is_array(array_key_exists(` doesn't make much sense. I guess you were trying: a) is not array or b) lacks a specific key.
Using a temporary variable you can do something like

```
if ( !is_array($meta=wp_get_attachment_metadata($attach_id)) || !array_key_exists('sizes', $meta) ) {
    // ....
}
```

Or, in case you try to access the meta data more often (or simply as a coding style):

```
$meta=wp_get_attachment_metadata($attach_id);
if ( !is_array($meta) || !array_key_exists('sizes', $meta) ) {
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Simply making the code cleaner makes it much easier to debug.+1

Comment: btw: the if condition _could_ be reduced to `if ( !isset($meta['sizes']) ) ... ` since php [doesn't complain](https://3v4l.org/hVXTM) (not a warning, not a notice) when $meta is `false`. Not my style, but possible....

Answer (score 0):

You could drop a ternary into that thing to uglify the hell out of it.

```
if ( is_array(array_key_exists('sizes',wp_get_attachment_metadata($attach_id)) == false) ?: array() ){}
```

This way if the attachment metadata does not exist, it will provide an empty array, which in turn will produce a false from array_key_exists, which is similar to the behave of the desired code.